# PHP date not parsed probably

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have an array of date strings like this in php.

```
28.09.18 13:42
28.09.18 14:12
28.09.18 21:18
28.09.18 21:23
28.09.18 21:28
10.04.19 23:36
```

My goal is to change the format to something like `Y-m-d H:i:s`. So I try this code.

```
foreach($dates as $date) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)).PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
2018-09-28
2018-09-28
2018-09-28
2018-09-28
2018-09-28
1970-01-01
```

As you can see the last date is wrong. Why it's not parsed probably? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use the second answer.

Comment: I think `strtotime` assumes `4/10/2018` (April) and `10-4-2018` (April) but using dots is ambiguous as to whether it is April or October.  `28.09.18` is not ambiguous as there is no 28th month but there is a 9th.

Comment: Now I use  DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y h:i', $date). But it always returns false

Comment: `h` is only 12 hour time use `H` for 24.  Also format it `DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y H:i', $date)->format('Y/m/d')`.  This is your friend `print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());`.